# Solution for Error converting data type nvarchar to decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a question about converting data type nvarchar to decimal, in a procedure when i update those informations my solution break in a error about converting. So this is my code:

**My Code:**

```
objGrupoComplementar.CusteioSegurado = (reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("CusteioSegurado")));
objGrupoComplementar.CusteioEstipulante = (reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("CusteioEstipulante")));
objGrupoComplementar.ProLabore = (reader.GetDecimal(reader.GetOrdinal("Prolabore")));
```

**and this is My Error:**

```
"Erro ao Alterar Cadastro Grupo Complementar: Error converting data type nvarchar to decimal."
```

Error in converting nvarchar to decimal

Anybody know how i fix this error ??
Thanks.

Comment: Please copy your code into your question. It's much easier to read code within the question than open a link to an offsite image.

Comment: Did you do some research? Do you understand what the error is telling you? It's also not thrown from the code you show.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize some reusable code in order to be able to parse the string as a decimal. Most likely the string is either null, empty or composed of non digit characters. Create a static extensions class and try the methods below.

```
public static decimal ConvertAsDecimal(this string input, decimal defaultValue = default(decimal))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
    {
        decimal result;
        if (decimal.TryParse(input, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return defaultValue;
}
```

Or like this for a nullable decimal:

```
    public static decimal? ConvertAsDecimalNullable(this string input, decimal? defaultValue = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            decimal result;
            if (decimal.TryParse(input, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return defaultValue;
    }
```